# What techniques can I use to solve $ \int$ $ \small{\dfrac{2}{t^2(a-b)+2ct+(a+b)} \space dt}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to calculate the following integral:

> $$\int \dfrac{2}{t^2(a-b)+2ct+(a+b)}dt$$

I've been going through an old university textbook (at the age of $44$) just to see if I fully understand all the course material.  I have completely forgotten how to do quite a bit of integration, although I'm not sure this was ever covered.  Or maybe I'm being stupid.  The example starts off with a substitution, which I understand, but I don't understand how to work out what the substitution ends up with.

I have tried using substitution and integration by parts but I'm struggling. Can anyone provide some pointers?  All my working out is in scribbles on pages, so I've avoided adding it.

Comment: If you complete the square you'll get a denominator of the shape $T^2 \pm A^2$ and each of these is standard.

Comment: Okay, so I completed the square: $$\int {{2\mathrm dt}\over{(a-b)(t+(c\(a-b))^2+a+b-(c^2)\(a-b)^2}}$$

Comment: I see, I can get an arctan(u) solution with substitution now, thanks.  It's messy, but with real numbers, it wouldn't be.

Comment: It may not be $\arctan$, if the constant is negative then there are two real factors so you'll get a couple of $\log$ terms instead.

Comment: The constants aren't specified, so the arctan solution is the only one I can reach based on what is available.

Comment: That is not so: you must distinguish the three cases $a-b-\frac{c^2}{(a-b)^2}>0$, $a-b-\frac{c^2}{(a-b)^2}<0$ and $a-b-\frac{c^2}{(a-b)^2}=0$.

Comment: Another perhaps far more cumbersome idea: factorize the denominator (quadratic formula or completing the square is fine), then expand the integrand into [partial fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Examples). Of course you'll still have to be wary of the several possible cases.